# Terraform For each loop on object and pass to child module

Tags: object, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a AWS s3 lifecycle rule of complex type (object) in my variables.tf file and have assigned it to a variable. Afterwards, I am using for_each loop to iterate over the object and passing this variable from a parent module to a child module where s3 resource is being created where I am stuck and I am not sure if my approach is correct or not. I know that for_each loop only accepts maps and sets but I could not find any resource to convert object to map and I am confused if I should convert object into map in my case.

I am new to Terraform and using Terraform v1.0.5 and the errors below are not of any help which I also tried to search but of no luck. I am trying to implement it for the last two days .I would appreciate if someone could please guide me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parent module `xyz-parent-module` should pass the variable  `rule_xyz` like this: -

```
module "xyz-parent-module" {
  source = "./aws-module/s3-bucket-module"

  for_each = var.lifecycle_rule_60_days
  rule_xyz = {
    lifecycle_id    = each.value["life_id"]
    prefix_value    = each.value["prefix_val"]
    enabled_value   = each.value["bucket_enabled"]
    expiration_days = {
      days_value = each.value["expiration_list"].expiration_days
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Now, it is not giving errors in `xyz-parent-module` and passing variables to child module fine but now I am getting same errors in child modules. I have tried to follow your approach in child module but I am not using `rule_xyz = {` in child module since I do not have to pass variables to another module anymore and it is my child module where resource should be created. Can you please help me in this or add a code snippet in your answer. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Can you please share the code where you are facing the issue? Also, you should not remove the existing code from the question. Instead, you can add an update note and ask follow-up questions. It will help others as well.